# No puedo agregar controlador en proyecto MVC ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, mvc

He creado un proyecto MVC con Entity Framework en un equipo con Visual Studio 2015 (con las debidas actualizaciones).

Pude agregarle un controlador vinculado a una de mis entidades, para probarlo. Una vez verificado su buen funcionamiento, quise continuar dicho proyecto en una netbook que tiene Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 RC.

Deseo agregar (obviamente) el resto de controladores para el resto de entidades, y al hacer click con  botón derecho sobre la carpeta "Controllers" buscando "Agregar->Controlador", esta última opción NO aparece.

¿Qué puede estar pasando...?

Comment: Mira esto, creo que te puede servir: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model

Comment: Dónde se origina el problema, en ¿VS 2015 o 2017RC?

Comment: En 2017 RC. ¿Puede ser que tenga que ver el hecho que el archivo del proyecto (originario de VS 2015) está siendo "llevado y traído" a la netbook con 2017 RC vía Dropbox...? ¿Hay algo que no se copia..?

Comment: ¿Lograste solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Extraño que no aparezca, pero puedes crear una clase en tu carpeta `/Controllers/` que herede de `Controller`y sigues la convención para nombrar tu controlador ejemplo: `public class MoviesController : Controller { // code here }` de igual forma para sus vistas lo ordenas en la carpeta `/Views/Movies/Index.cshtml`

Comment: Gracias Víctor Roque. Justamente quiero evitar eso, por la facilidad y rapidez que me brinda la ejecución del comando por menú contextual, que me crea controlador y vista en un mismo paso. Si no tengo otra alternativa para el trabajo en la netbook, así lo haré. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Me paso lo mismo, tenía abierto en **Visual Studio** la carpeta del proyecto más no la solución, solo ve hacia donde esta tu proyecto y ejecuta la solución, es el archivo con extensión `.sln`.